# How do I get only a dataframe from a function that returns a DF and a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently working on a function that will `return` a dataframe, but also contains a matplotlib plot. It looks something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])
    df['a'] = np.random.randn(n)
    df['b'] = np.random.randn(n)*2
    df['c'] = np.random.randn(n)*3
    plt.plot(df.a,color='red')
    plt.plot(df.b,color='green')
    plt.plot(df.c,color='blue')
    return(df)

function(100)
```

The problem is that this function (in Jupyter at least) outputs both a plot and a DataFrame. I would like to use the DataFrame (`df`) as an input in another function, and I have not been able to successfully extract solely the DataFrame for this purpose.

I have tried to use function(100)[0] and a few variations of this, to no success.

I have also realised that placing the `return(df)` block above the `plt.plot` lines will return only the DataFrame but no plot, and I'd like to have both (DataFrame AND plot) show in the output cell when I call `function`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function to have an option not to plot:

```
def function(n, plot=True):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])
    df['a'] = np.random.randn(n)
    df['b'] = np.random.randn(n)*2
    df['c'] = np.random.randn(n)*3
    if plot:
        plt.plot(df.a,color='red')
        plt.plot(df.b,color='green')
        plt.plot(df.c,color='blue')
    return(df)
```

Then:

```
>>> function(n)
# plot + output
>>> function(n, plot=False)
# output only
```

*NB. use `def function(n, plot=False):` to make it not plotting by default*

Answer (score 0):

`Return` statement also allows dicts.

```
 return {
         'my_df':df,
         'my_plot': plt.plot
         }
```

Then, you can access the contents using:

```
function_= function(100)
returned_df = function_['my_df']
returned_plot = function_['my_plot']
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add a variable to save what is returned by the function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])
    df['a'] = np.random.randn(n)
    df['b'] = np.random.randn(n)*2
    df['c'] = np.random.randn(n)*3
    plt.plot(df.a,color='red')
    plt.plot(df.b,color='green')
    plt.plot(df.c,color='blue')
    return(df)

new_df = function(10)
```

then new_df here is df only.